# How to verify bi-weekly Google Apps Script trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the following to setup a biweekly trigger in my spreadsheet script.

```
function createBiWeeklyTrigger() {
  // Trigger every other Monday at 09:00.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('send_biweekly_feedback_solicitation')
      .timeBased()
      .everyWeeks(2)
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .atHour(6)
      .create();
}
```

However, when I look at the current project triggers, this trigger doesn't look any different from a weekly trigger (see screenshot below).

[image]

How can I tell if this trigger has in fact been setup correctly -- to run every TWO weeks?

Comment: is there code inside `send_biweekly_feedback_solicitation` function that stores / logs whether the it started and finished successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anyway [to get the clock settings on an existing trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#), looks like you've just got to trust it's set up OK. [You can star the issue if you'd like to see this as a new feature](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2562).